# How to label axes in Matplotlib using LaTeX brackets?

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

How to label axes in Matplotlib using LaTeX expression `$\langle B_{\mathrm{e}} \rangle$`?
I need to label my axis with nice looking "<" and ">" LaTeX brackets.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try `ax.set_ylabel(r'$\langle B_{\mathrm{e}} \rangle$')` for labeling Y-Axis or `ax.set_title(r'$\langle B_{\mathrm{e}} \rangle$')` for the title of the axes.

Comment: This also works for data visualization with seaborn (based on matplotlib) like a charm